# error TS5014: Failed to parse file 'tsconfig.json': Unexpected token / in JSON at position 57

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I moved my typescript project to a win 7 computer.
I get this error when the tsconfig works perfectly fine in my win 10 computer.
I removed the last two trailing commas as suggested [here](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1462) and the error persists.

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    //"inlineSourceMap": true,                  /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    //"inlineSources": true,                    /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
    "sourceMap": true,
    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    "outDir": "./src/ts-built",
    //"rootDir": "./src",
    // "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowJs": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  }
}
```

It also surprises me that when I run

```
tsc --init
```

I obtain:

> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'init'.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you run *npm install*

Comment: JSON can NOT contain comments so literal JSON implementations will fail with that error. Some JSON-config friendly readers will allow the JS-style comments. Also ensure that the implementation understands `//` *and* `/*..*/` forms. Some only understand one form of JS-style comments.

Comment: I suspect this JSON reader understands neither form.. refer to the documentation/resource that claims or implies that JS-style comments are allowed. If such documentation cannot be found, they are probably not valid. As, again, pure JSON does not have or support comments..

Comment: (And this is one of the reasons I find pure JSON unsuitable for configurations.. another being indeterminate ordering, and another being lack of literal new lines in strings, and..)

Comment: I was not aware that JSON can NOT contain comments. Did not have any problem with that in my other computer. That was the issue, thanks a lot. If you post that as an aswer I will accept it

Answer (score 6):

I kept getting the same error messages because I had a *tsc* installed globally. I uninstalled it and installed the *typescript* package which solved the problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue where running "tsc --listFiles" gave me an "error TS6046" re: my use of "target": "es2022" in my tsconfig.json (same error shown in different answer below). After I upgraded (npm install -g typescript), the error disappeared. Now "tsc -v" shows I have v5.1.6, rather than 2.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it happened because I downgraded my typescript. After that I removed **tsconfig.json** file then tsc worked. Probably There was some new config's that added in newer versions of Typescript. Therefore I start to figure out witch one is newly added:

```
    error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'strict'.
error TS6046: Argument for '--target' option must be: 'es3', 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'esnext'
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'resolveJsonModule'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'checkJs'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'exclude'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'include'.
```

then It solved. There is a beautiful tip that i was using these configs for weeks on newer version of typescript and their working.

Check it and see what happens :)